# Strange behaviour of date parsing for small years

Tags: java, date, calendar

Let the code roar:

```
    Calendar cal = javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseTime("1030-01-01+01:00");
    System.out.println(cal.getTime());
```

// output: **Fri Dec 26 00:00:00 CET 1029**

```
    System.out.println(new org.joda.time.DateTime("1030-01-01").toDate());
```

// output: **Fri Dec 26 00:06:32 CET 1029**

Why for small years are results so crazy?

Answer (score 3):

I think this is for dates less than October 15, 1582 (Gregorean cutover), that is we are getting into Julian times